# Ion-slides is shown in the view only if ion-content scroll=false

Tags: ionic-framework

I need a scrollable page with ion-slides directive. If i set scroll=true in ion-content the slider is not shown on the page. I'm running ionic 1.3.1 and using the new ion-slide directive. This is my code,

```
<ion-content class="padding" scroll="false">

    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item no-padding">
        <img class="full-image" src="http://12.jpg">
      </div>


      <div class="item ">
         <button  class="button  icon-left ion-android-navigate  button-stable">Directions </button>
         <button  class="button  icon-left ion-ios-telephone  button-stable">Call </button>
         <button  class="button  icon-left ion-android-share-alt  button-stable">Share</button>
      </div>
    </div>


     <div class="slide-wrapper1">
        <ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
          <ion-slide-page>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/375x468/">
          </ion-slide-page>
          <ion-slide-page>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/375x468/0000">
          </ion-slide-page>
          <ion-slide-page>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/375x468/">
          </ion-slide-page>
        </ion-slides>
      </div>


    <h4>About </h4>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping text.
      </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

what am i doing wrong, How do i get the ion-slides to work in a scrollable page?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping the inside of your ion-slide-page with an ion-content like:

```
   <div class="slide-wrapper1">
    <ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
      <ion-slide-page>
       <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x468/">
       </ion-content>
      </ion-slide-page>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
```

I would like to note that this should work with Android.  I think I had to remove the ion-content for iOS to work on the device.

*Edit - Also, my outside ion-content is set to true

Comment: Tried your solution, it still doesn't work... I downgraded to the old ion-slide-box directive.

Comment: ok, yea the only real difference I can still see between what I am doing and anything you are doing is that I do not have this one div `<div class="slide-wrapper1">`

Comment: It was a some css to control the height of the slider 
slide-wrapper {
  height: 310px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}